# Query Update row with data from another row in the same table

Tags: mysql, updates

I have table like this... with 3000+ records..

```
╔═════╦════════╦═════════════╗
║ id  ║  text  ║  parent_id  ║
╠═════╬════════╬═════════════╣
║   1 ║  asas  ║           0 ║
║   2 ║  fgh   ║           0 ║
║   3 ║  jkl   ║           0 ║
║   4 ║  kkk   ║           0 ║
║   5 ║  test  ║           0 ║
║   6 ║  asd   ║           0 ║
║   7 ║  dsa   ║           0 ║
╚═════╩════════╩═════════════╝
```

how to change the parent_id value to same like id? to like this...

```
╔═════╦════════╦═════════════╗
║ id  ║  text  ║  parent_id  ║
╠═════╬════════╬═════════════╣
║   1 ║  asas  ║           1 ║
║   2 ║  fgh   ║           2 ║
║   3 ║  jkl   ║           3 ║
║   4 ║  kkk   ║           4 ║
║   5 ║  test  ║           5 ║
║   6 ║  asd   ║           6 ║
║   7 ║  dsa   ║           7 ║
╚═════╩════════╩═════════════╝
```

and more..... until 3000+records..

Comment: UPDATE table SET parent_id = id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as simple as:

`update yourtable set parent_id = id`